# Is ‘with in’ in the phrase ‘be used with in construction’ grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, dictionaries

In the ‘2. p. Grammar’ section of the ‘Webster’s New World College Dictionary’, I found the phrase ‘be used with in construction’. The phrase ‘in construction’ is idiomatic and has an adjectival meaning, which led to my confusion.

I thought that a preposition should be followed by a noun or something that serves as a noun, but there’s no noun after ‘be used with’. I didn’t understand why the preposition ‘with’ is in front of the idiom ‘in construction’.

Could you please explain if this is grammatically correct?

Refer to the ‘2. p. Grammar’ section at https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take

> **take**
> **2.**  *to get by action not involving force or skill; obtain, acquire, assume, etc.*
> **p.**  *Grammar*
>  to have or admit of according to usage, nature, etc.; be used with in construction
>        <sub>*a
> transitive verb takes an object*</sub>

Comment: to have or admit of according to usage, nature, etc; be used with in construction
_a transitive verb takes an object_. •  'take something' = 'be used with something when  one is (correctly!) putting together a construction'.  • 'When a number falls below 1 the characteristic of [its] logarithm takes a minus sign [often an overline, a bar over the characteristic].'

Comment: "In construction" is not really an idiom, it's more of a technical term.  It doesn't refer to the act of _constructing_ (building) a sentence, but the act of _construing_ (interpreting) it ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/construction), definition 1).  This may be a potential source of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

## There is no *with + in* here

You have misparsed the phrase: *with + in* is not part of the same constituent. It is merely two words from two separate phrases that occur next to each other by happenstance. The elisions in the original have led you to misread it.

> **take**
> **2.**  *to get by action not involving force or skill; obtain, acquire, assume, etc.*
> **p.**  *Grammar*
>  to have or admit of according to usage, nature, etc.; be used with in construction
>        <sub>*a
> transitive verb takes an object*</sub>

All this is saying is that *to take something* “in Grammar” means *“to be used **with** something **in** a grammatical construction”*.

The transitive object *something* has been left out for brevity’s sake after the typical manner of printed dictionary where space is too dear to waste on obvious elements, and so you have misread this as somehow saying *with* + *in* when it does not say that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree after I **finally saw it** via Tinfoil Hat's repost of the actual dictionary entry! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has been really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the entry is fine. It is short for *be used with [something] in [a] construction*

You can substitute *is used with in construction* for *takes* like this:

> *a transitive verb **takes** an object*
>
> *a transitive verb is **used with** an object **in** [a clause]*

And, yes, they might have added *[something]* for clarity, as did the *OED*:

> **take** *verb*
> *transitive. Grammar.* Of a word, clause, or sentence: to have or require (a particular inflection, case, mood, etc.) as part of the
> appropriate construction.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your help. It has been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The phrase is "be used with" + "in something". It says that that something is used with something else in doing something.

An example might be "fruits are **used with** ice-cream **in** making a milkshake"

Comment: It's written in an abbreviated style because it's a dictionary entry, not a full sentence.

Comment: @ Stuart F So, based on dubious’s response, is it correct to understand that “be used with in construction” implies the structure “be used with (something) in construction”? I would appreciate your clarification.